# Call JSP file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have an HTML file and I want to use javascript to call a JSP file.

It doesn't have to be javascript, I'm just looking for the easiest way to call the JSP file from the HTML file.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I should have added that I want to call the JSP file in the background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML/CSS/JavaScript runs at the client side. Java/JSP runs at the server side. The client and server are two distinct environments which usually runs at physically different machines, connected with each other by a network with the communication protocol being HTTP.

When the client requests a specific URL at the server, the server will run specific Java/JSP code and return a HTML/CSS/JS response back to the client. The client (webbrowser) will in turn execute the HTML/CSS/JS.

Knowing this fact, it should be obvious that the only way to let JavaScript access/invoke some Java/JSP code is to send a HTTP request to the server side. This can be done in several ways: using `window.location` to do a synchronous GET request, or `form.submit()` to do a synchronous GET or POST request, or `XMLHttpRequest#send()` to do an asynchronous (ajaxical) request.

But you after all don't need JavaScript for this at all. A simple HTML link or form is also sufficient.

```
<a href="page.jsp">link</a>
```

or

```
<form action="page.jsp">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This will open the JSP file. If you'd like to run some business stuff prior to opening the JSP page, then better let the URL point to a Servlet like `<a href="page">` which in turn forwards the request to the JSP page like

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

To learn more about the wall between Java/JSP and JavaScript you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about the Ajax. Where u have background JSP page to do the processing in that case try this link [link text](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Once u understand this u can switch to JQuery of Prototype's ajax which is way better :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a some kind of form and in the action attribute of your form to put yourPage.jsp.Something like that

```
<form action="index.jsp" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```